# Collective nouns and auxiliary Do

Tags: british-english

The word “family” is a collective noun so afaik it should be singular in a sentence like this:
Does your family go on holiday at Christmas?
However, what would be the appropriate short answer?
Being part of the family I’d go with “Yes we do”. However, in this case there will be a mismatch between Does (question) and Do (answer).
Any help?

Comment: Just say "yes". No harm in a short answer. You could continue "We usually go to Biarritz" or whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no reason why a question and an answer need to have the same subject. If the subjects demand different verb conjugations, then the verbs won't be the same.  This is completely normal in English (and in most languages that conjugate verbs).

Do any families go on vacation?
Yes, mine does.

Does your family go on vacation?
Yes, we do.

Does anyone want to answer?
Yes, I do.

Are you here?
Yes, I am here.

Is anyone here?
Yes, we are here.

Comment: Thank you very much for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

I see someone has tagged this "British-English". Many collective nouns, including  "family", can be used as plural nouns, **especially in British English**.

> My family, who have lived on this island all their lives, are
>   determined to remain here.

[Noun-verb agreement - BBC (British)](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv358.shtml)

> family
>
> noun
>
> (SOCIAL GROUP)   A1 [ C or U + **sing/pl verb** ]
>   a group of people
>   who are related to each other, such as a mother, a father, and their
>   children:
>   A new family **has/have** moved in next door.

[Family (Cambridge Dictionary)](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/family)